# QGraphicsScene item is drawn at twice(x2) position

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene

(warning crossposted on: https://forum.qt.io/topic/105158/qgraphicsscene-item-is-drawn-at-twice-x2-position)

In the following code I am creating a custom widget which has a subclass of QGraphicsScene embeded in it. My aim is to click and add a point to the scene. A point is my subclass of QGraphicsItem (GIPoint). I want to move that point around and later connect it to other points and make a spline path.

The problem I am facing is that the point is not drawn at where I click but at a place which is formed by doubling the mouse-event's scenePos() coordinates. So if I click at (100,100) the point is drawn at (200,200). I suspect that I have misunderstood the coordinate system despite reading the documentation.

The question [How to add item in a QGraphicsScene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922821/how-to-add-item-in-a-qgraphicsscene) seems relevant but the proposed solution to transform the mouse-event's coordinates via `mapToScene(event->pos());` actually doubles up the position (before it will print that it draws on same position but it would then be x2. Now it also prints it as x2).

So I am asking additionally to point me to some simple-to-digest advice on how the widgets placement works. btw. is `QRectF GIPoint::boundingRect() const {
        return QRectF(pos().x(), pos().y(), 5, 5);`
correct regarding the (x,y) coordinates of the rectangle?

My example code follows:

```
/* use the following pro:
QT += widgets core gui

CONFIG += debug console
SOURCES = example.cpp
TARGET = example
*/
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QRectF>
#include <QPointF>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QDebug>

class GIPoint : public QGraphicsItem{
public:
    GIPoint(QGraphicsItem * parent, const QPointF &position);
protected:
    QVariant itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value) override;
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
    void paint(
        QPainter *painter,
        const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
        QWidget *widget
    );
};
class GraphicsSceneWidget : public QGraphicsScene {

public:
    explicit GraphicsSceneWidget(QObject *parent);
    ~GraphicsSceneWidget();
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

class VectorGraphicsWidget : public QWidget {
public:
    VectorGraphicsWidget(QWidget *parent);
    ~VectorGraphicsWidget();
private:
    GraphicsSceneWidget *myGraphicsSceneWidget;
};

// implementation
GIPoint::GIPoint(
    QGraphicsItem *parent,
    const QPointF &position
) : QGraphicsItem(parent) {
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    setPos(position);
    qWarning() << "GIPoint::GIPoint() : init at " << position;
}
QVariant GIPoint::itemChange(
    GraphicsItemChange change,
    const QVariant &value
){
    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange) {
        qWarning("position changed");
    }
    return value;
}
QRectF GIPoint::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(pos().x(), pos().y(), 5, 5);
//  return QRectF(0,0, 5, 5);
}
void GIPoint::paint(
    QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
    QWidget *widget
){
    (void )option;
    (void )widget;
    QPointF xx = scenePos();
    QRectF rect = QRectF(xx.x(), xx.y(), 10, 10);
    qWarning() << "painting: scenePos " << scenePos() << ", rect " << rect;
    QBrush brush = QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern);
    //painter->fillRect(rect, brush);
    painter->drawRect(rect);
}

GraphicsSceneWidget::GraphicsSceneWidget(QObject *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{}
GraphicsSceneWidget::~GraphicsSceneWidget(){}
void GraphicsSceneWidget::mousePressEvent(
    QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event
){
    GIPoint *gip = new GIPoint(Q_NULLPTR, event->scenePos());
    addItem(gip);
    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
}

VectorGraphicsWidget::VectorGraphicsWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    myGraphicsSceneWidget = new GraphicsSceneWidget(this);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(myGraphicsSceneWidget);
    myGraphicsSceneWidget->setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500));
    QGridLayout *centralLayout = new QGridLayout;
    centralLayout->addWidget(view);
    setLayout(centralLayout);
    myGraphicsSceneWidget->addRect(
        QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100),
        QPen(Qt::black),
        QBrush(Qt::green)
    );
    view->show();
}
VectorGraphicsWidget::~VectorGraphicsWidget() {
    delete myGraphicsSceneWidget;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setApplicationName("test");
    app.setOrganizationName("myorg");
    app.setOrganizationDomain("myorg.com");

    QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow();
    w->resize(500, 500);
    w->setCentralWidget(new VectorGraphicsWidget(Q_NULLPTR));
    w->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `boundingRect()` and the `paint()` methods is respect the coordinate system of the item, not the scene. So the solution is not to use `scenePos()` in both methods but `0, 0`:

```cpp
QRectF GIPoint::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10);
}
void GIPoint::paint(
    QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
    QWidget *widget
){
    (void )option;
    (void )widget;
    QRectF rect = QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10);
    qWarning() << "painting: scenePos " << scenePos() << ", rect " << rect;
    QBrush brush = QBrush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern);
    painter->fillRect(rect, brush);
    painter->drawRect(rect);
}
```

Although I would recommend using QGraphicsRectItem as it implements what you have done.

Comment: yes thank you! I have just figured it out myself but edited first my crosspost! In fact I made the boundingRect to return (-0.5, -0.5, 10, 10). Thanks for the suggestion to inherit QGraphicsRectItem. It makes sense.